# Displaying Icon depending on Filetype

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

When a user uploads a file to my site i want it to display an image depending on the filetype I.e - png file uploaded it will then display file with the file icon and view button

i have this currently in my Upload model

```
 public function getIconAttribute() {

    $extensions = [
        'jpg' => 'jpg.png',
        'png' => 'png.png',
        'pdf' => 'pdf.png',
        'doc' => 'doc.png',
    ];

    return array_get($extensions,$this->extension,'unkown.png');
}
```

and i have this in my view

```
<img src='../../../public/img/{{ $file->icon }}' style="padding:5px;" class="img-responsive center-block" />
```

im unsure how to make this work i have the icons in my img folder etc its just getting it to work thats the problem

Comment: Why you have the extensions array inside the method? Declare a protected variable on the Model.

Comment: because im unsure of what i am doing lol

Answer (score 1):

This can be done rather easily with [css attribute selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).

```css
img[src$=".jpg"]:after{
    content: 'jpg';
}
img[src$=".png"]:after{
    content: 'png';
}
```

```html
<img src='img.jpg' style="padding:5px;" class="img-responsive center-block" />
<img src='img.png' style="padding:5px;" class="img-responsive center-block" />
```

Comment: It sure works in my snippet though. I can't help you if all I have is "it doesn't work".

Comment: aye your snippet works great apologies , i tried adding the code you shared but nothing happens ?

Comment: you can name icons with the name of the extension and use the extension in the img url as file name

Comment: img[src$=".png"]:after {
  background: url('/img/png.png');
} i done this in Css and still shows broke image link